# For loop in Bash to take action on just first positional arg

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following script:

```
for arg in "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$varN" ; do  
  echo $arg; 
done;
```

What I am trying to accomplish is `do` something if I am iterating and I am on the first positional argument. I think it would be something like:

```
for arg in "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$varN" ; do  
  if [ *some condition* ]; then
    *action*
  else
    if [ *first positional arg* ];
      echo *first positional argument*
  fi
done;
```

Beginner with bash so go light on me :).

Comment: Do the action for the first argument, then use a for loop for the succeeding arguments. It's more readable and less lines of codes to write.

Comment: @alvits Made an edit.

Comment: This isn't a good question. People will just tell you to process $var1 before the loop. If that doesn't work for you for some reason then you need to provide a more detailed question that provides an explanation why you need to do this inside the loop instead of before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the first positional parameter to a variable. Then use `shift` to remove it from the positional parameters, and loop over the parameters.

```
firstarg=$1
# do stuff with $firstarg
shift # remove first arg
for arg; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could handle this. You could process $var1 before the loop or add some condition like the following:

```
handled_first=false
for arg in "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$varN" ; do 
  if ! $handled_first; then
    # do stuff
    handled_first=true
    continue
  fi
  # other stuff
done
```

Comment: In your code, `#  other stuff` will be executed for `$var1` as well. In fact, it will do all for `$var1` and will skip `# do stuff` for all others.

Comment: While `! $handled_first` is intriguing, I suggest not confusing beginners with it, because it's not at all obvious that _commands_ `false` and `true` are being executed.
I suggest using an actual conditional (`[[ … ]]`) instead - even though it's noisier.

Answer (score 0):

If I have this right and you want to do one thing while on the first argument passed to a script but another thing while on the others:

```
echo $1
for arg in "${@:2}"; do
    *action*
done
```

Replace the `echo $1` with whatever you want to happen for the first argument. The `"${@:2}"` is an array of all the arguments starting with the second one, so you can use that for the other actions.